# How I can add a tooltip to a PHP short code?

Tags: php, wordpress, tooltip, shortcode

I'm trying to add a tooltip function (on hover) to the following shortcode:

```
 <?php
 echo do_shortcode('[um_loggedout]Accedi /<br>Registrati[/um_loggedout]');
                     ?>
```

I've already created a css class with all the parameters needed, but since I am not
big with php I don't really know how I can make it work.
Anyone can help me? If this detail can be useful I am working via Wordpress.

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

What does that output to the frontend? Can you apply your hover styles to one of the classes generated by the shortcode?

---Update---

So you're trying to create a login form appear when they hover over the logged out text?

If so, I think you can use `[ultimatemember form_id=####]` to display the login form, you'll need to replace the #### with the login form ID. If the `<br>` tag in the above example works, why can't you wrap the text in a div?

```
<?php
 echo do_shortcode('[um_loggedout]<div id="display-login-form">Accedi /<br>Registrati</div>[/um_loggedout]');   ?>
```

Then with jQuery/JavaScript, on hover make the box display?

```
$('#display-login-form').on('mouseover', function() {
   $('[insert form container id here]').show();
})
```

You'll need some logic/ability to hide it if they change their mind.

Comment: It is for the login button who should be visible in the main header for the users who are not logged.
The shortcode was generated by the plugin *Ultimate Member*.

I would like that once users go hover on this text-button the login form show as popup/tooltip. 

Yes I can apply a class but I don't know how correctly do it via php.

Comment: Updated my answer